# Databricks Error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, azure-databricks, pypi

I am completely new to this Databricks.

In Databricks i have tried running the following packages in its python notebook

```
# Library Section
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from io import StringIO
import os
import smtplib
import time
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import datetime
```

All these packages are running fine when i am running the cell individually. But when i am trying to run the packages on the auto schedule mode, its giving the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4076398358532638> in <module>
      8 import pandas as pd
      9 import numpy as np
---> 10 import sqlalchemy
     11 from sqlalchemy import create_engine
     12 from io import StringIO

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
```

Absolutely no idea what is this problem all about. Can someone please help me with this.

Edit 1: i installed the following libraries in Databricks

1. psycopg2
2. sqlalchemy
3. flask_SQLAlchemy

but still the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say I had installed the following libraries in Databricks, How exactly have you installed `sqlalchemy` library?

By default, Databricks clusters will not have `sqlalchemy` library installed on the runtime selected.

[image]

You need to install the `sqlalchemy` library explicitly and run the above command.

```
 pip install SQLAlchemy
```

[image]

Comment: i had tried importing the library via import library option that we get on the landing page of Databricks.

Comment: Is there any solution for this now?